# Two holomorphic functions which have a simple roots at the origin

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to solve the following question:

Let $f$ and $g$ be functions holomorphic on the closed unit disk. Assume that f and g have simple zeros at the origin and that g has no any other root in $\{z:|z|\leq 1 \}$. Assume also that $|f(z)|<|g(z)|$ on the boundary of the unit disk. Show that $|f'(0)| < |g'(0)|$.

I try to apply Schwarz Lemma but I couldnt get the result. I also used the maximum modules principle which implies that for all $z$ in the closed unit disk $|f(z)|<M$ where M is the maximum of g on the closed unit disk but how can I go further? Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum modulus principle is the key;  $\displaystyle  \left|\frac{f}{g}\right|<1$ on the boundary of the disk, hence $\displaystyle  \left|\frac{f}{g}\right|<1$ inside the disk. So $\displaystyle \frac{\left|f(z)/z\right|}{\left|g(z)/z\right|}=\left|\frac{f}{g}\right|<1$ for $z\not =0\,,$ and then you can probably finish the rest, using the fact that $\displaystyle f(0), g(0)=0\,.$

Comment: So you apply the principle to the function $\frac{f}{g}$? But the function $\frac{f}{g}$ is not defined at the origin? So how we solve that problem?

Comment: Define it at the origin by the limit of $f(z)/g(z)$ as $z\to 0\,,$ which exists since they are both holomorphic and $0$ at the origin, and since the origin is a simple $0$ of $g\,,$ so $g'(0)\not = 0\,.$

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot.

Comment: @JLA, isn't it possible that $\frac{\vert f(z)/z\vert }{\vert g(z)/z \vert}$ is $1$ in the limit (instead of strictly less than $1$)?

Comment: @TheSubstitute No because of the maximum modulus principle it is bounded by something less than $1$.